# vbscript gives different error in different browser

Tags: vbscript

The functionality of the code is that once the upload button is clicked a text file should be created in the given location.

With the current code I am getting `uncaught referenceerror is not defined at htmlinputelement.onclick` error in other browsers and ' `error 429 activex component can't create object`' in internet Explorer.

Please help Me, my machine is windows 10

Comment: Is this ASP Classic?

Comment: This looks like it might be new development? I would strongly caution against writing browser-side VBscript as it is being deprecated. JavaScript would be a more suitable language for this task. See: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/08/02/update-disabling-vbscript-internet-explorer-windows-7-8/#50W34DXqaQKzElFy.97

Comment: yes ZorgoZ it is asp classic, not in a postion to rewrite the application, need a fix

Answer (score 0):

> uncaught referenceerror is not defined at htmlinputelement.onclick error in other browsers

Only Internet Explorer supports VBScript, so in other browsers the `<script language="VBScript">` is ignored. This means the function isn't created. This means it isn't defined when you try to call it.

> error 429 activex component can't create object' in internet Explorer

Here the function *is* created, but it doesn't work.

Internet Explorer doesn't allow webpages to use ActiveX to write to the user's hard disk. It would be a serious security problem.

You can only use that component in non-webpage contexts (such as in a Classic ASP application).

---

The closest you can come is to [create a URL with the data embedded in it that the user can download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server).

Comment: Thank you.. it is an inhouse application and writes the file to a folder in a secured network drive.It is written in classic asp, not in a position to rewrite need a fix please

Comment: @newbee — Then you need to move the logic server-side. Client-side code can't do that.